# Trigger call on softphone from browser with asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk

I'am currently working on asterisk and need to integrate few functions on our website.
I have registered a sip number on a softphone and I need to trigger a call from that softphone from the browser.  I know how to run AGI or FastAGI with php, but not sure how I can do that task.

I'm not sure if the following idea will work.
On the browser dial my registered softphone and then dial the another number.
Not sure if that will work.

Any help will do! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger call on your asteisk

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out+deliver+message

After that you need auto-answer it on your phone,something like this

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Polycom+auto-answer+config

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this approach (i.e. making call to the softphone instead of from the softphone) used with TSP/TAPI, but it's more complicated and less logical (it messes your local call log) than passing number to softphone that supports it (I think most do) with protocol handler - same way as Skype registers itself as callto: link handler or old emule used ed2k: links.
Assuming you are running windows - to associate protocol with application few registry entries need to be created that instruct browser how to convert link target into appropriate command line. If softphone supports it it would be probably available as option within installer or some action in settings window.
You may find this instruction helpful:
http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/browser_integration.php